# Is killing Baron worth losing a turret?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've noticed that every time me and my team go for baron we lose a turret. Is the boost from baron really worth losing a turret? Doesn't baron just give health and mana regen? 
Can a baron kill alone bring a sure lose to a victory or is pushing more important?

Answer (score 4):

Killing Baron Nashor gives you the following:

a buff that lasts for 4 minutes that gives:

- 40 ability power
- 40 attack damage
- 3% of your maximum health in health regeneration per 5 sec.
- 1% of your maximum mana in mana regeneration per 5 sec.

it also gives 300 gold.

Compare that to a tower which only give 150 gold and i'd say getting nashors is worth it.

A baron kill alone doesn't necessarily turn a loss into a victory although it might help a lot. 
Because you gain a huge advantage in the next teamfight usually allowing you to ace their team and push.Or if that's not the case then you can usually push with your team and get 1 or more turrets tipping the game in your favor

Answer (score 4):

Depends on What turret we are talking about.

**Worth:**

- T1 (First turret that can be broken)
- T2 (Second turret that can be broken)

**Not worth:**

- T3 (Turret from base)
- Turret from Nexus

As @SergeBekenkamp said in his answer:

> Killing Baron Nashor gives you the following:
>
> a buff that lasts for 4 minutes that gives:
>
> 40 ability power 40 attack damage 3% of your maximum health in health
>   regeneration per 5 sec. 1% of your maximum mana in mana regeneration
>   per 5 sec. it also gives 300 gold.

The best moment to go for baron are:

1. When all lanes are pushed.
2. After an ACE (if your team is good on health/survivability).
3. After a push when the opponents are dead or recalling.
4. All from above
5. GOLD RULE: When you are **SURE** about they don't know you are going to do Baron. (Wards are EXCELLENT tool for this. sometimes the opponent is going jungle red/blue, defending bottom/mid lane and your team go there and do Baron quickly)

Comment: It's 300x5+25 gold actually. 1525 gold total.

Comment: If you are counting the GLOBAL gold, Yes.

Answer (score 2):

I would say 1 of you make sure that all lanes are pushed while other doing baron , and if you're doing baron after winning a team fight that would be a lot easier

Comment: Care to elaborate why its important to keep pushing all the lanes, while fighting Baron? Or why you should wait until after winning a team fight?

Answer (score 1):

One tower generates you 150 gold for each member of your team whereas baron gives you 300 gold to every member of your team plus 900 exp points and a buff that makes you stronger so i would say it makes up for the tower...

Comment: And why do you consider that buff to outweigh the losses?

Comment: One tower generates you 150 gold for each member of your team whereas baron gives you 300 gold to every member of your team plus 900 exp points and a buff that makes you stronger so i would say it makes up for the tower...

Comment: Then I suggest you edit your answer and put in that information ;-) Comments are 'second-class citizens' and might get deleted if there's too much chit-chat. Plus a better answer means more upvotes for you!

Answer (score 1):

Killing Baron is definately worth taking over loosing a turret, because in the late game...turrets are pretty worthless. I just view them as a tanky level 20 champion with no items. So by taking Baron your team would get twice the the gold than the other team just taking a turret AND you would have a buff advantage (which you would use to push them or force a teamfight)

75% of the time getting Baron is a game ender.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is. Baron gives 300(iirc) gold if you kill it to each person, pseudo-blue to your team, and 40 ad/ap, and massive hp regen (there may be other stats on it but I forget it). The tower gives 150 gold per person and no buff. 300+many buffs is better then 150 and no buffs in most cases, however, if your team can't kill baron fast you're giving them a large chance to push and baron will deal a lot of damage to your team, allowing an ace opportunity so in that case, protecting the tower is better.

TL;DR: Baron is better if you can kill it fast, if not, save the tower.

Answer (score -1):

it really debends if you guys are losing "gold wise" and the other team is recalling or dead that is the moment but i would rather slay the herald as the buff is forever but only on one teamate